# Trying to find max length of tooltip in different browsers

Tags: cross-browser, tooltip

I want to show some amount of data on tooltip. But different browsers having different max length for for tootip.
Max length of tooltip for IE is 512 and Fount max length for tooltip for chrome browser 618 Charecters. Still didn't get any valid proof for chrome. 
Can anybody please help to find the max length of tooltips in different browser?